# How can I mark checkbox checked when the user input a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have this problem where I want to mark the checkbox checked when the user input a certain value. For example when the user inputted "FAAS" the checkbox should be check. How to do this?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" name="faashidden" id="faashidden">
 <input id="faasfrontandback" name="faasfrontandback" type="checkbox">
 <label for="faasfrontandback">FAAS Front & Back</label>
```

and when the user will input something in `faashidden` and click the button the checkbox should be checked. Here is my javascript code:

```
var faas = $("#faashidden").val();
if (faas.value == "FAAS") {
       document.getElementById("faasfrontandback").checked = true;

}
```

Comment: var faas = $("#faashidden").val(); already sets faas to the value of input box, no need to do faas.value

Comment: so how to properly do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#faashidden").keypress(function(e){
    var faas = $("#faashidden").val();
    if (faas == "FAAS") {
       $("#faasfrontandback").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

It adds an event listener on the input. Every time the user hits a key while focused on the input, the function checks the content of the input and checks the box if it's "FAAS".

Edit: you may also want to check the box whether the input is "FAAS" or "faas". In that case, convert the input to lowercase and compare the result with "faas". See below:

```
$("#faashidden").keypress(function(e){
    var faas = $("#faashidden").val().toLowerCase();
    if (faas == "faas") {
       $("#faasfrontandback").prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: how about if input box has already a value and the user will not type anymore?

Comment: You could add the inner code of the keypress listener to the $(document).ready() section for that case: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. Event more, the listener should be declared inside $(document).ready() too, for safety.